Estimating impact of correlated dependent variables on the independent variable using Principal Component Regression
I have a large no. observations of 50 columns of correlated data and I want to estimate their individual impact on the dependent/target variable.
The approach I believe might work is first estimate principal components using the independent variables to get rid of multicollinearity and then with the principal components as the exogenous variables run a regression against the target.
Since Principal components are just linear combinations of original variables/columns, I could estimate the individual impact of the original variables using the estimated OLS weights and PCA weights.
See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55148756/interpreting-ols-weights-after-pca-in-python
Is this a good Idea? It sounds rather trivial but I have been trying to find research papers implementing this but haven't found much.
Thanks for your support.
